# Rails if @model.save is throwing an error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Message model. Whenever I run `if @message.save` in my controller I get this error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "conversation_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I just want to redirect if save fails.

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      # redirect
    else
      # render new
    end
  end
```

My schema for messages

```
  create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "body",                                    null: false
    t.integer  "conversation_id",                         null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: If you want to redirect if save fails, why do you have `# render new` commented out in `else`-clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the reason this is happening is because there is no validation in your actual model, only in the db. Therefore, it is passing the validation to continue saving, but the db has a problem with it. Simply include a validation in your model, and it will return false:

```
validates :conversation_id, presence: true
```